# Multiplicative structure of a family of functions and $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a question about a multiplicative structure and $\sigma$-algebra.

Let $S$ be a set and $\mathcal{J}$ be a familly of $\mathbb{R}_{+}(:=[0,\infty[)$-valued bounded functions on $S$, having the following properties:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
u \wedge 1,u \wedge v,(u+1)\wedge v \in \mathcal{J}  &{\rm \,if\,}u,v \in \mathcal{J}\\
c_{1}u+c_{2}v \in \mathcal{J} &{\rm if\,}u,v\in \mathcal{J},c_{1},c_{2}\in \mathbb{Q}_{+}(:=\mathbb{Q}\cap ]0,\infty[)\\
(0 \in \mathcal{J}  {\rm \,if\,necessary})
\end{array}
\end{equation}

> **Question**
>
> Is there a family of $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions on $S$ ( denoted by
>   $\mathcal{K}$) such that $\mathcal{K}$ is multiplicative (i,e, $f,g
>  \in \mathcal{K} \Rightarrow fg \in \mathcal{K}$) and
>   $\sigma(\mathcal{K})=\sigma(\mathcal{J})$　and **$\mathcal{K}$ has the following property:**  $c_{1},c_{2} \in \mathbb{Q},f,g \in \mathcal{K} \Rightarrow c_{1}f+c_{2}g \in \mathcal{K}$
>
> where $\sigma(\mathcal{J}),\sigma(\mathcal{K})$ is the
>   $\sigma$-algebra on $S$ generated by $\mathcal{J}$, $\mathcal{K}$
>   respectively.

**My attempt**

Define $\mathcal{K}^{'}:=J-J:=\{u-v:u,v \in J\}$. Let $\mathcal{K}$ denote the uniform closure of $\mathcal{K}'$.

By a simple calculus, we can get the following properties about $\mathcal{K}$:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
c_{1}u+c_{2}v \in \mathcal{K} &{\rm if\,}u,v\in \mathcal{K},c_{1},c_{2}\in \mathbb{Q}\\
u \wedge v, u \vee v \in \mathcal{K}  &{\rm \,if\,}u,v \in \mathcal{K} \\
u \wedge 1 \in \mathcal{K} & {\rm \,if\,}u \in \mathcal{K}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Where I used the following identity :
\begin{align*}
(f-g)\wedge (h-j)&=[(f+j)\wedge (h+g)]-(g+j)\\
f \vee g&=-[(-f)\wedge (-g)] \\
(g-f)\wedge 1 &=((f+1)\wedge g)-f 
\end{align*}

**I want to get the propery**
$f \in \mathcal{K},q \in \mathbb{Q}  \Rightarrow |f-q|(=(f-q)_{+}-(f-q)_{-})\in \mathcal{K}
\cdots(\ast)$.

Because the function $x \mapsto x^{2} $ on a finite interval $[a,b]$ may be approximated uniformly by linear combinations of functions $x \mapsto |x-c|$,
 if $(\ast)$ holds, it follows that $\mathcal{K}$ is multiplicative.

Thank you in advance.